# Why is Symfony messenger sending a message twice before rejecting?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

I have implemented a Message Transport protocol in a `Symfony`-Project, that implements the `TransportInterface`.
While playing around with it and learning how it works, I came across a weird issue that I like to elaborate on and understand more:

When a message is missing a corresponding message handler, the Message Transport will first be called with the method `send`, followed by a method call to `reject`.

I would assume, that the method `reject` will be executed only. Why is the message being sent once more? I figured out, that it has nothing to do with the setting of `max_retries`.

My custom Message Transport is doing the following:

1. `get`: it reads the message from a custom table inside the `get`-method.
2. `send`: it just logs "send" into the console with the corresponding envelope
3. `reject`: it just logs "reject" into the console with the corresponding envelope

What I am doing for testing is:

1. I write manually a message into the message-table, which automatically causes the `get` method to retrieve the corresponding message
2. messenger tries to find a suitable message handler and finds nothing because there is none yet
3. messenger is printing to the console:

> 07:58:06 INFO      [messenger] Received message
> App\Message\IngestMessage ["class" => "App\Message\IngestMessage"]
>
> 07:58:06 WARNING   [messenger] Error thrown while handling message
> App\Message\IngestMessage. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay.
> Error: "No handler for message "App\Message\IngestMessage"." ["class"
> => "App\Message\IngestMessage","retryCount" => 1,"delay" => 1000,"error" => "No handler for message
> "App\Message\IngestMessage".","exception" =>
> Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\NoHandlerForMessageException^ {
> …}]

4. then it logs "SEND" to the console because the `send`-method will be executed which is doing `console.log("SEND")`
5. it logs "REJECT" to the console because the `reject`-method will be executed which is doing `console.log("REJECT")`

### Code:

`messenger.yml`:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
             async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
             ingest:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_INGEST)%'
                retry_strategy:
                  max_retries: 5
                  delay: 1000
                  multiplier: 2
                  max_delay: 0
        routing:
             'App\Message\IngestMessage': ingest
```

`IngestDataTransport.php`:

```
class IngestDataTransport implements TransportInterface
{

    public function __construct(private readonly DataBucketManager $dataBucketManager)
    {}

    public function get(): iterable
    {
        $dto = $this->dataBucketManager->pop();

        echo ".";
        if(!$dto) {
            return [];
        }

        dump("GET", $dto);

        $event = IngestMessage::fromDataBucketDTO($dto);
        $envelop = new Envelope($event);

        return [$envelop];
    }

    public function ack(Envelope $envelope): void
    {
        // TODO: Implement ack() method.
        dump('ACK');
    }

    public function reject(Envelope $envelope): void
    {
        // TODO: Implement reject() method.
        dump('REJECT', $envelope->getMessage());
    }

    public function send(Envelope $envelope): Envelope
    {
        dump('SEND', $envelope->getMessage());

        return $envelope;
    }
}
```

Once I implement a corresponding message handler, neither the `SEND`-method nor the `REJECT`-method is executed, which makes total sense.
However, why comes `reject` with a `send`? It would always duplicate a failed message.

Comment: Have a look to : https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#saving-retrying-failed-messages

Comment: @Weenesta-MathieuDormeval you cited the document that I was reading for building everything. It doesn't say anything about the reported behavior.

Comment: You can set a `failure_transport` queue in `messenger.yaml`